Zero initial condition with a linear system of first-order differential equations
Consider linear system of first-order differential equations
$$\frac{d}{dt} \pmatrix{x1 \\ x2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} = \pmatrix{a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn}}  \pmatrix{x1 \\ x2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} + \pmatrix{g1 \\ g2 \\ \vdots \\ g_n}$$
When $g_n (t) = 0$ (for all $n$ and all $t$) the system is homogenous.
Given this, and given zero initial condition $x_n(t=0) = 0$ (for all $n$), then only trivial solution $x_n(t) = 0$ (for all $n$ and all $t$) exists due to lack of source term.
Question: How to proof that no non-trivial solution exists for any such homogenous system with zero initial condition?
